# Android - cant play my RSTP YouTube links on VideoView but can play other links

Tags: android, youtube, android-videoview

I upload videos to youtube and save the link on my database.
Then I enter in the Gallery where i see all the vids.
I get the RSTP link with:

```
 try {
                        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
                        String getURL = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/"+urlv;
                        System.out.println("YEYEYEY0"+getURL);
                        //String getURL = "http://inmamarti.com/android/ufo/yt2rtsp/example/index.php?ytid="+urlv;
                        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(getURL);
                        HttpResponse responseGet = client.execute(get);  
                        HttpEntity resEntityGet = responseGet.getEntity();  
                        if (resEntityGet != null) {  
                            ye =EntityUtils.toString(resEntityGet);
                                    //do something with the response
                                   // Log.i("GET RESPONSE",EntityUtils.toString(resEntityGet));
                                }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

where urlv is the video id (www.youtube.com..?v=ID_VIDEO)
When i play videos uploaded in 3gp (low definition) by my app, videoviwver says This video cant be played. If i play videos uploaded in mp4 by my app it says Private video.

But if i play videos that are on youtube, uploaded by others, they get played successfully!

What i'm doing wrong? The upload??
I use post and get requests in php and zend to upload the video cause i wasnt able to do it using youtube api and gdata

To upload, first i get the youtube token url and value:

```
    $yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube($httpClient);
// create a new VideoEntry object
$myVideoEntry = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry();
$myVideoEntry->setVideoTitle('Concerto');
$myVideoEntry->setVideoDescription('Concerto');
// The category must be a valid YouTube category!
$myVideoEntry->setVideoCategory('Music');

// Set keywords. Please note that this must be a comma-separated string
// and that individual keywords cannot contain whitespace
$myVideoEntry->SetVideoTags('cars, funny');

$tokenHandlerUrl = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/action/GetUploadToken';
$tokenArray = $yt->getFormUploadToken($myVideoEntry, $tokenHandlerUrl);
$tokenValue = $tokenArray['token'];
$postUrl = $tokenArray['url'];
```

and then i upload the video and save in bbdd

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    //HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.inmamarti.com/android/ufo/printr.php?nexturl=http://www.hola.com");
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(youtubeToken+"?nexturl=http://www.inmamarti.com/android/ufo/printr.php");
                    MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
                    entity.addPart(new StringPart("token", youtubeTokenValue));
                    File imageFile = new File(nomarch); // .. get your image file
                    entity.addPart(new FilePart("file", imageFile, null, "file"));
                    httppost.setEntity(entity);
                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    String result = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
                    System.out.println("RESPONS·E "+result);
```

What im doing wrong?